# Powershell - update attributes in Active Directory based on JSON file

Tags: json, powershell, foreach, active-directory

This is an extraction of my json file:

```
[
    {
        "ProductionSubfolders": "XYZ",      
        "ProductionSubfoldersDN": "OU=XYZ,DC=bla,DC=root,DC=local"
    }
]
```

ProductionSubfolders = the values are the name of an Organizational Unit in Active Directory

ProductionSubfoldersDN = the values are the assocciated DistinguishedName of the Organizational Unit

I want to add an entry for the Active Directory attribut called "description" of the Organizational Units that are listed in the json file - in this case "ABC" and "XYZ".

The new value of the attribut "description" in Active Directory should be "Test + the name of the OU", so in this case : "Test-ABC" and "Test-XYZ".

This is what I have:

```
$json = Get-Content "C:\prod.json" |ConvertFrom-JSON


foreach ($item in $json) {
    
    foreach {$item1 in $item.ProductionSubfoldersDN} {
       $name = $item.ProductionSubfolder
       $p= Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $item1 -Properties description| Select description
       if ($p.description -notlike "*Test*") {Set-ADObject -Identity $item1 -Add 
       @{description="Test-$name}
    }
}
```

It works. For the OU "ABC" there is a new description attribut value in AD and for the OU "XYZ" is also a new description attribut value in the AD.
But the name of the attribut is wrong. It is "Test-ABCXYZ" for both OUs, instead of "Test-ABC" for the OU "ABC" and "Test-XYZ" for the OU "XYZ".

I know that this is because $item.ProductionSubfolder contains both names: "ABC" and "XYZ". But I do not know how to change it, how to separate the names and match them correctly to the associated ProductionSubfolderDN.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Using this kind of Json is not very recommended, the one you had on the question I answered was much better and _safer_ than this. Do you still want to use this?

Comment: That's true... but yes for several reasons I have to use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json consists of 2 properties and both of them are arrays, the way you could iterate *correctly* over them would be using a `for` loop. I personally don't think it's a good idea using this kind of object to update AD Objects but here is how you can do it.

First you need to get the count of elements on the arrays, and then use a `for` loop with that count:

```sh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$count = $json.ProductionSubfoldersDN.Count

for($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++) {
    $dn = @($json.ProductionSubfoldersDN)[$i]
    $description = 'Test-{0}' -f @($json.ProductionSubfolders)[$i]
    try {
        Set-ADOrganizationalUnit $dn -Description $description
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Above code assumes that the properties of your Json will have the same count (`$json.ProductionSubfoldersDN.Count` must be equal to `$json.ProductionSubfolders.count`).

Comment: Yes, the always have the same count. 

I just found out that the code works only if there are **at least two values** for the "ProductionSubfoldersDN" and "ProductionSubfolders" keys in the json File. If there is only one value for "ProductionSubfoldersDN" and only one "ProductionSubfolders". Do you know why?

Comment: See the edit, the array sub-expression operator `@(..)` should fix that issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! :D Unfortunately the sub-expression operator @() does not fix this issue. Do you have any other guess?

Comment: @user18209625 update the question showing how this Json looks like

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @user18209625 that edit should fix the problem but yeah, this is why I mentioned this Json is not good..

Comment: Amazing, thank you! It fixed the problem! 
...Yeah, you're absolutely right...

Comment: @user18209625 glad it worked, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

a solution to link the value of subfolder to subfolderDN:

```
foreach ($item in $json)
{
    foreach ($name in $item.ProductionSubfolders)
    {
        foreach($ou in $item.ProductionSubfoldersDN)
        {
            if ($ou -like 'OU=' + $name + '*')
            {
                $n = 'Test-{0}' -f $name
                
                $name + ' is inside ' + $ou;
                $ou;
                $n;
                #Set-ADOrganizationalUnit $ou -Description $n
            }
        }   
    }
}


ABC is inside OU=ABC,DC=bla,DC=root,DC=local
OU=ABC,DC=bla,DC=root,DC=local
Test-ABC
XYZ is inside OU=XYZ,DC=bla,DC=root,DC=local
OU=XYZ,DC=bla,DC=root,DC=local
Test-XYZ
```

i test if the OU contains the name of OU from subfolders using `like` which is not case sensitive (use `clike`for case sensitive)

this solution is functional whatever the order of OU..